# Get value from <td> where <th> matches text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With a system that I use you can create custom fields. These fields all have the same html and css. Now I would like to get the value td where the th is week.

Now I use:

```
   var week = $(this).find('td.bug-custom-field:last').text();
```

Which works but then I have to make sure it always is the last field. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
   <table>
   <tr>
   <th class="bug-custom-field category">Name</th>
   <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">Test</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <th class="bug-custom-field category">Week</th>
   <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">23</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: That is not a valid HTML table

Comment: `:contains()`, `.index()` and `.eq()` exist …

Comment: If you break your question into separate parts, the answer becomes much easier to see: (a) You need to know which header (counted from the left) contains your text. (b) You want to find the cell which is in a certain position (counted from the left). Both of these are easily found online. The only thing that remains is feeding the result of (a) into (b).

Comment: It's a vertical table so it is valid? I try $( "th.bug-custom-field.category:contains('Week')" ) to get the right th but then how do I get the td value from that. Do you have a example?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal other than missing the optional `tbody` please advise why this is not a valid HTML table.  Do you actually think that `th` can only appear in the `thead` ?  or that you can only have `th` in the first `tr`?

Comment: @rienkwind can you elaborate on what you mean by "I have to make sure it always is the last field"

Comment: I can change the position of the custom fields in the backend. So if I use :last on td I will get the right value from the last td. But if another user changes this position than the code will still look for the last td. So im trying to create something that always gets the value from td where th is "Week" no matter what the position of the custom field is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Var 1:

```js
var week=0;
$('table tr td').each(function(){
 if($(this).prev().text()=='Week'){
  week=parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
 }
});
console.log(week);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
   <tr>
     <th class="bug-custom-field category">Name</th>
     <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">Test</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <th class="bug-custom-field category">Week</th>
     <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">23</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Var 2:

```js
var week = $('table').find('td.bug-custom-field:last').text();
console.log(week);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
    <th class="bug-custom-field category">Name</th>
    <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">Test</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <th class="bug-custom-field category">Week</th>
    <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">23</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have most of the details you need.  Once you have the `th` the most robust solution is to go up to the row and then use find to find the `td`.  The alternative is a simple `.next()` but is more likely to break if the layout changes.

```
var th = $("th.bug-custom-field.category:contains('Week')")
var row = $(th).closest("tr");
var week = $(row).find('td.bug-custom-field:last').text();
```

```js
var weekTH = $("th.bug-custom-field.category:contains('Week')")
var weekTR = $(weekTH).closest("tr");
var weekTD = $(weekTR).find('td.bug-custom-field:last');
var week = $(weekTD).text();
console.log(week);
```

```css
th { text-align:left; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="bug-custom-field category">Name</th>
    <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">Test</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <th class="bug-custom-field category">Week</th>
    <td class="bug-custom-field" colspan="5">23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```