# looping over the tr structure and trying to create a array list

Tags: jquery

I have this code which seems as though it should work, but somehow it is giving me an error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLTableRowElement].childrow

```js
idsInOrder = [];
$(this).find('tr').each(function(obj, item) {
  if ($(item).closest(".parent").data('question-id') == $(item + ".childrow").data('answer-id')) {
    idsInOrder.push($(item + ".childrow").data('status'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center">
  <tr class="parent" data-question-id="100">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="childrow" data-answer-id="100">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="childrow" data-answer-id="100">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent" data-question-id="160">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent" data-question-id="120">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="childrow" data-answer-id="120">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="childrow" data-answer-id="120">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="parent" data-question-id="150">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `parent` can be first or last or anywhere in the middle. What am I missing here? I am stuck.

Comment: You're trying to append an Element object to a string selector which won't work. What is `this` a reference to? `item` will be the `.parent` element, so `closest()` seems redundant. Similarly `item` will be the `.childrow` element so the `if` condition is flawed. It would help if you could describe the output you're trying to achieve as the logic you've shown is not going to work, even if the syntax problems were fixed.

Comment: Also, `align="center"` was removed from the HTML5 specification, so shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: i am trying to get the parent of the child elements, and the childrens inside the array so i can run them as needed

Comment: You're using `.closest()` where it looks like you want `.prevAll()` or `.siblings()`

Comment: i tried with prevAll, but it captures the very first element, i want to capture the parent whole child i am trying to pick up

Comment: the output i want is: if the parent's data-parent-id matches with child's data annswer-id i will add the values of td inside a hidden input field because i am using using a push to append the values to an array

Comment: You should be able to get a working solution from this very similar question (two working answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679526/get-value-from-td-where-th-matches-text/50680195#50680195

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from <td> where <th> matches text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679526/get-value-from-td-where-th-matches-text)